# Drainage problem

Tags: drainage

I built a room to my existing house which created a pitch on the roofline.  When it pours rain, the water pools under my window and seeps into my house.  I have put up gutters and also a rain collector, but the rain is so fierce that it pours so fast, bypassing the gutter and pooling under my window.  Does anyone have a suggestion as to how to fix this?  Is it a roofing problem -- maybe having a divertor so that the rain does not collect so much at that one point? or a drainage under my windows?  I don't even know who to ask to help me fix this!  Thank you

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. A picture or a diagram would really help here.

Comment: Sounds like it was built wrong, but there's no way to know for sure without seeing it.  Please [post some photos](http://meta.diy.stackexchange.com/a/524/33)

Comment: I agree that somethings wrong and photos would help. Several of the leakage problems similar to your's have been from narrow or plugged gutters. If they don't drain they over flow. Not sure if you have 1 problem or maybe 2. But if you have clean gutters and can turn a hose on in the down spout without over flowing you may need a diverter into the gutter.

Comment: How high is the window-- is the water pooling on the ground, or is water from the gutter running down the wall and entering the window casing?  If the latter, aside from fixing the gutters, you need the window fixed.